# Как сложить результаты цикла foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Здравствуйте, подскажите, есть следующая конструкция, выводящая поочередно цены товаров, умноженные на количество товаров...

```
foreach ($order['product'] as $product) {
     echo ($product['price']*$product['quantity']);
}
```

а как получить итоговую сумму по всем товарам?

Сейчас получаю на выходе цифры 1000 2000 1500 2300 - а нужна общая сумма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в качестве альтернативного варианта:

```
$result = array_sum(array_map(function($o){ 
                          return $o['price'] * $o['quantity']; 
                      },
                      $orders));
```

---

вариант получше:

```
$result = array_reduce($orders, function($sum, $o){ 
                         return $sum + $o['price'] * $o['quantity']
                      }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($order['product'] as $product) {
    echo ((int)$product['price']*(int)$product['quantity']);
    $sum += (int)$product['price']*(int)$product['quantity'];
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: Отлично, все работает ) Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
$summ = 0;
foreach ($order['product'] as $product) {
    $summ += (float)$product['price'] * (float)$product['quantity'];
}
echo $summ;
```

Comment: а приведение типов тут зачем?? `$arg_1 = '2';
$arg_2 = '2';

var_dump($arg_1 * $arg_2); // int(4)` В результате математических операций типы автоматически преобразуются в *integer*

Comment: @Эдуард дак чтобы цены в целых числах и штуках считать :) есть у тебя 1.5руб * 1.5кг, а результат 1р вместо 2.25

Comment: @Звягинцев Денис эмм... Вы камент мой скопируйте, выполните, и посмотрите результат.

Comment: @teran ну, я не много не о том :)

Comment: @Эдуард да и я не о том, вдовесок написал :)

Comment: Да, что-то я забыл про дроби. Исправил. А для каждой переменной приведение я сделал, чтобы отсечь всякие случаи типа 1.4руб и т.п. -  потому что в другом решение получилось что-то не то.